# How can I get a specific attribute value from string HTML code snippet

Tags: jquery

I have a string that contains an HTML code snippet and I want to get the value of the `id` attribute from the element `dt`.

```
var myHtml = "<dt id='119'>Email</dt><dd id='container'>my text</dd>";
```

Expected result:

```
var myId = 119;
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Simply can use `.attr()`

```js
var myHtml = "<dt id='119'>Email</dt><dd id='container'>my text</dd>";
var myId = $(myHtml).first().attr('id');
alert(myId);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should target the `dt` explicitly, in case other ids are added before the target id (or the order reversed), but yes this will work.

Comment: ^ `<dt>` @TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the string in jQuery and simply use `attr`

```
var myId = $(myHtml)
          .first() // get the first element - <dt>
          .attr("id"); // get the id
```

Note that you could just use `attr` since jQuery only gets the first attribute if multiple elements are involved, but using `first` is more *semantic*, or at least I think so.

Comment: @Brandao glad to have helped you

Answer (score 2):

If the order of elements may be changed you should find the specific `dt` then gets its `id` attribute. `attr()`, by itself, will only return the first matching id found so is not a robust solution:

```
$(myHtml).filter('dt').attr('id')
```

You have to use `filter()`, and not `find()` as they are all top level elements in that HTML snippet.

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ghwzsao0/

The safer alternative, if the content can vary, is to wrap the html in another temp element that `find()` can be used with:

```
$('<div>').html(myHtml).find('dt').attr('id')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ghwzsao0/1

Answer (score 1):

You can test this in console:

```
$("<dt id='119'>Email</dt><dd id='container'>my text</dd>").eq(0).attr('id')
```